# Broken automatic line breaking in section titles when ulem and hyperref are used

Tags: hyperref, formatting, ulem

I am trying to use the `ulem` package to underline section titles while still being able to have automatic line breaking:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl} 
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\begin{document}
    \addtokomafont{section}{\uline}
    \section{A section title so long that it causes a line break. A section title so long that it causes a line break.}
\end{document}
```

This works like expected. Once I add the `hyperref` package, the automatic line breaking seems to be disabled, e.g.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl} 
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
    \addtokomafont{section}{\uline}
    \section{A section title so long that it causes a line break. A section title so long that it causes a line break.}
\end{document}
```

yields an overfull line for the section title.

If a remove the `\addtokomafont{section}{\uline}` the line breaking is back again, but of course there is no underlining any more ...

How can I achieve underlined section titles with automatic line breaking enabled?

NOTE: I know I shouldn't use underlining for section titles, but this was not my decision.

NOTE 2: For those who complain about using underlining at all: The issue also occurs if I use strikeout via `\sout` instead of `\uline`, which is definitely useful during the editing process of a document.

Comment: Remark to the NOTE. Alas, TeX primitive `\dump` is not applicable to a stupid boss/institution. :-)

Comment: Break manually. Or use short titles.

Comment: Sorry for being so late; I probably forgot about my comment because I greatly dislike underlining. I know it's not your fault, but… `;-)`

Comment: Well, non of the answers tries to solve the actual incompatibility between `uelm` and `hyperref`. But since it's a good workaround and I also dislike underlining, I accept it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This requires all section titles use the optional argument, but at least does the breaking you require.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\renewcommand\othersectionlevelsformat[3]{%
  \ifnum\pdfstrcmp{#3}{\thesection}=0
    \uline{#3\autodot\enskip}%
  \else
    #3\autodot\enskip
  \fi
}

\begin{document}

\section
 [A section title so long that it causes a line break.
  A section title so long that it causes a line break.]
 {\uline{A section title so long that it causes a line break.
  A section title so long that it causes a line break.}}

\subsection{Whatever}

\end{document}
```

Some trick has to be used to underline also the section number, but not do the same to subsections.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

use the optional argument and `\uline` in the title itself:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl} 
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
    \section[A section title so long that it causes a line break. A section title so long that it causes a line break.]
    {\uline{A section title so long that it causes a line break. A section title so long that it causes a line break.}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This idea is not bad. But unfortunately, the solution is not complete: The section number is not underlined if I use `\uline` inside the `\section` command.

Comment: If you need it for all section numbers: `\renewcommand\thesection{\uline{\arabic{section}}}`

Comment: Is it possible to also have the space between the section number and the section title underlined? With your solution, there is still a gap.